# Zend MVC query string rewrite

Tags: zend-framework, iis-7, url-rewriting

Background : I am using IIS 7 (Windows 2008) and Zend Framework

What I am working on is rewriting a link site/blog?Id=1 to site/blog/1
Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
<rule name="RedirectUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^blog$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^Id=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="blog/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
<rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^blog/([^/]+)/?$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="blog?Id={R:1}" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your IIS allows rewrite?

Comment: Yes, I have other rewrite rules that work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead as mention in zend doc

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
         <system.webServer>
             <rewrite>
                 <rules>
                     <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                         <match url="^.*$" />
                         <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                                 matchType="IsFile" pattern=""
                                 ignoreCase="false" />
                             <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}"
                                 matchType="IsDirectory"
                                 pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                         </conditions>
                         <action type="None" />
                     </rule>
                     <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                         <match url="^.*$" />
                         <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                     </rule>
                 </rules>
             </rewrite>
         </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

[src](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Comment: I already have these rules, and they work. I just can't get my blog app with the Id query string to trigger a different rule.

Comment: @user1063323 once this in place , do all routing related work through Zend_Route unless you are renaming index.php

Comment: OH! I will look into that. It does sound like a more direct approach! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule    ^blog/([0-9]+)/?$    blog?id=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle requests
```